# Is it possible to send a SOAP request to a REST endpoint?

Tags: rest, soap

I'm working with an old ERP system that is capable of sending SOAP requests.
Unfortunately the endpoints I would like to send my requests to uses REST.

Is it possible to send a SOAP request to a REST endpoint?

BR Kresten

Answer (score 1):

You can send whatever you want to a `REST` endpoint.

You could have a "gatekeeper" `REST` endpoint that accepted `SOAP` in a `POST` payload and converted it to whatever representation the other endpoints required and returned that representation. e.g. `JSON`. So in effect it becomes a `SOAP` to `JSON` converter.

If you can only send `SOAP` direct from an ERP system to your endpoint, your endpoint could accept the `SOAP` in a `POST` request and do whatever it wanted with it. `SOAP` is just `XML`, so the endpoint could just parse it to get the info it would "normally" get via "traditional" `REST` such as `JSON`.

You could combine the two approaches. Your ERP system could send `SOAP` to the "gatekeeper" endpoint which converts the `SOAP` to `JSON` and sends the converted content to the intended endpoint.